# Funcion para sumar al clickear pero con valores dentro del parentesis

Tags: javascript

```
<button onclick="funcion6();">
    Dame click!
</button>
<p id="demo6">Yo cambiare al darle click</p>


<script>
function funcion6(a,b) {
    return a + b;       
}
document.getElementById('demo6').innerHTML = funcion6(2,3);
</script>
```

Esto ya me funciono haciendo.

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('demo5').innerHTML = funcion5(8,9);">Click para hacer la pinshi suma</button>
```

Pero estoy buscando la manera de hacerlo sin poner tanto código en el metodo on click. Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta definiendo que encierre toda la logica y asi solo definir la funcion.

Por ejemplo:

```js
function funcion6(){
  document.getElementById("demo6").innerHTML = "Cambie!";
}

function funcion5(a,b) {
    return a + b;       
}

function Sumar(){
  document.getElementById('demo5').innerHTML = funcion5(8,9);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="funcion6();">
    Dame click!
</button>
<p id="demo6">Yo cambiare al darle click</p>
<p id="demo5"></p>
<button onclick="Sumar()">Click para hacer la pinshi suma</button>
```

La funcion `Sumar()` hace todo lo que tenias en el `onclick` del button.

Comment: Como no se me ocurrió hacer otra función que hiciera la suma , a veces uno solito se complica las cosas, gracias :D